# Locating someone's IP address with a MAC address

Tags: ip-address, mac-address

I asked someone for their IP address, but they gave me their MAC address.  Is it possible to get their IP address with their MAC?

Comment: are you aware that it's completely possible that a device has a MAC address, but no IP address at all? The reverse (getting MAC from IP) is possible in most cases (i.e. when the device is connected and accessible), and the usual way to get IP from MAC would be to scan all possible IPs in the range you're interested for their MACs, and check if any of the MACs matches the one you know. Still, I'd say your question is somewhat too broad and general to be answerable as it is.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought.  I just wasn't sure if there was a direct way of retrieving the IP from just the MAC.

Answer (score 3):

If that person is in the same Local Area Network (LAN) (same building), then you can try to use ARP lookup. On windows, it would be arp -a. Outside of LAN, it is not possible to guess IP from MAC. Try to contact that person and ask for an IP. You may ask them to go to [http://ipchicken.com](https://ipchicken.com) to get their PUBLIC IP.